# How can I make my code containing a For loop more Mathematica-style?

Tags: code-review, iteration

I know there are a lot of questions on this site regarding the use of `For`  loops and how to avoid them in *Mathematica*. However, in my case I believe it is justified, as I will show below. My issue is that for very large amount of iterations, the kernel crashes, and so I am looking for a more *Mathematica*-style solution to my problem.

---

The aim of my code is to compute successive values of an integral between two points `a` and `b` in a cumulative way, i.e., feed back the value of the previous integral into the new value and perform some calculations with the intermediate value. Here is a short code snippet that illustrates my situation:

```
MyIntegral[a_, b_]:= ...;
numericalLimit:=10^20;

For[i=0, i<numericalLimit, i++,
(
    myIntermediateValue=MyIntegral[i,i+1];

    (* ... some computations with myIntermediateValue *)

    myCumulatedValue+=myIntermediateValue;

    (* ... some computations with myCumulatedValue *)
)]
```

So as you can see, I need the iterative nature of the `For` loop in order to work with my cumulated value. Needless to say, as it has been reiterated before on this website (pun not intended), `For` loops are evil. Moreover, for very large values of `numericalLimit` the kernel crashes. So my questions are:

- How can I make this code more *Mathematica*-like?
- How can I optimize the computations so that my kernel does not crash for large values of `numericalLimit`?

Other answers on this website suggest using `Table` in similar situations, but I fear that it will actually be *less* efficient when considering $10^{20}$ copies, moreover I don't see how I will be able to cumulate my intermediary results.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can check `Nest`, `NestList`, and `Fold` commands. All though sometimes trying to find the `Mathematica` way of doing things make it much more slower.

Comment: Is it possible that you write down your `MyIntegral` more explicitly?

Comment: A quick answer: No.

Comment: @Buddha_the_Scientist The integral in question is a very simple one, there is no possibility to optimize it. My question is more related to the concept of the `For` loop and other iterative constructs.

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ What about recursive functions formalism such as `MyIntegral[]:=MyIntegral[]=...` kind of thing.

Comment: If it's such a simple function like this check out `Compile` and your function performance might improve by a few orders of magnitude.

Comment: My "No" means I think personally `For` and *Mathematica*-style are mutual exclusive. But all roads lead to Rome, so one can achieve the same thing by other methods.

Comment: For iterative statements like this, it is almost always better to use `Do` instead of `For`. For more specific advice, knowledge of the nature of the commented calculations would be useful. For example what needs to happen with the output of those calculations? Given the number of iterations, preventing any memoryleak issues will be important.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Thank you. Can you please give an example on how to use it?

Comment: @Klangen sure: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compile.html#Examples

Comment: And I don't see any reason why `Do[
 myIntermediateValue = MyIntegral[i, i + 1];
 (*... some computations with myIntermediateValue*)
 myCumulatedValue += myIntermediateValue;
 (*... some computations with myCumulatedValue*),
 {i, 0, numericalLimit - 1}]` should not work.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher How is that any different than `For`, just with a different order of expression?

Comment: The difference is that the iterator is coped and that Mathematica has at least a chance to compile the body of the loop. In general, evaluate should be faster.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely try that.